# ng serve --o throws TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined from tslib.js

Tags: angular-cli

I tried to build an angular 8 project, so I followed the performed the following step:

```
ng new angular8project  
npm install bootstrap --save  
ng serve -o
```

While I issue the command `ng serve -o`, I am getting below mentioned error.

> ng serve -o
>   Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
>   TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
>       at setPrototypeOf ()
>       at Object.__extends (/home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:65:9)
>       at /home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:115:17
>       at /home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:314:6
>       at /home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:3:17
>       at Object. (/home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:9:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
>       at /home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:20:22
>       at /home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:10:17
>       at Object. (/home/s0057870/gitrepo/angular-demo/angular8proj/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:16:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)

Comment: anything on this?